# Spring MVC - @RequestParam causing MissingServletRequestParameterException with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

The follwing Spring MVC code throws MissingServletRequestParameterException,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class XXXXResource extends AbstractResource {

.....

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT
            , produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}
            , consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    )
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Representation createXXXX(@NotNull @RequestParam("paramA") String paramA,
        @NotNull @RequestParam("paramB") String paramB,
        @NotNull @RequestParam("paramC") String paramC,
        @NotNull @RequestParam("paramD") String paramD ) throws Exception {
   ...
   }
}
```

There are no stack traces in the logs, only the Request from Postman returns with HTTP 400 Error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` means  that the body of the HTTP request sent to the server should be one giant string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand `(&)` and will be `urlencoded` as his name implies.

`name=name1&value=value2`

this means that you should not user `@RequestParam` because the arguments are passed in the body of the http request.

So if you want to use this `content-type` from their doc:

> You convert the request body to the method argument by using an 
>   HttpMessageConverter. HttpMessageConverter is responsible for
>   converting from the HTTP request message to an object and converting
>   from an object to the HTTP response body. The
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter supports the @RequestBody annotation with
>   the following default HttpMessageConverters:
>
> ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter converts byte arrays.
>
> StringHttpMessageConverter converts strings.
>
> FormHttpMessageConverter converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.
>
> SourceHttpMessageConverter converts to/from a
>   javax.xml.transform.Source.

You should use `@RequestBody` with `FormHttpMessageConverter`, which will get this giant string and will convert it to  `MultiValueMap<String,String>`. Here is a sample.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT
        , consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        ,value = "/choice"
)
public
@ResponseBody
String createXXXX(@RequestBody MultiValueMap params) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("params are " + params);
    return "hello";
}
```