# Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody MultiValueMap

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Based on the answer [for problem with x-www-form-urlencoded with Spring @Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731070/spring-mvc-requestparam-causing-missingservletrequestparameterexception-with/33732140#33732140)

I have written the below @Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{email}/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST
            , produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}
            ,  consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    )
     public
        @ResponseBody
        Representation authenticate(@PathVariable("email") String anEmailAddress,
                                    @RequestBody MultiValueMap paramMap)
                throws Exception {


            if(paramMap == null || paramMap.get("password") == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password not provided");
            }
    }
```

the request to which fails with the below error

```
{
  "timestamp": 1447911866786,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/users/usermail%40gmail.com/authenticate"
}
```

[PS: Jersey was far more friendly, but couldn't use it now given the practical restrictions here]

Comment: Did you add consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} in @RequestBody?

Comment: How did you execute the request? add the code of (js,jquery, curl or whatever you use ) .

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case I use jquery ajax to post the data and the data is `JSON.stringify({"ordersToDownload":"00417002"}`

Comment: This is the code I use: `$.ajax({url:"/myurl", type:"POST", data: JSON.stringify({"someAttribute":"someData"}) })`

Comment: Check my answer out [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46983753)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

The problem is that when we use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this
we must remove the **@RequestBody** annotation.

Then try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(
  path = "/{email}/authenticate", 
  method = RequestMethod.POST,
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, 
  produces = {
    MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE, 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  })
public @ResponseBody Representation authenticate(
  @PathVariable("email") String anEmailAddress, 
  MultiValueMap paramMap) throws Exception {

  if (paramMap == null && 
      paramMap.get("password") == null) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password not provided");
  }
  return null;
}
```

Note that removed the annotation **@RequestBody**

*answer*: [Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin/38252762#38252762)

Comment: Thank you! Solves the problem. Now I wonder how do we explicitly remove the  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: it is not necessary @kholofeloMaloma

Comment: If anyone wondered why this works without any annotation, it seems Spring handles any non annotated arguments as if they have `@ModelAttribute, even though this behaviour is (sadly) not documented. And `@ModelAttribute does understand x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: public ResponseEntity<?> getToken(MultiValueMap paramMap)
IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Comment: Thanks for the info! As a newbie, I am wondering what's the reason behind this little odd behaviour for Spring to parse the payload and bind it to object?

Comment: I believe that should be **OR** as opposed to **AND** (if paraMap is null the get will produce NPE

`
   if(paramMap == null || paramMap.get("password") == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password not provided");
    }

`

Comment: Gives me an error No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap

Answer (score 102):

It seems that now you can just mark the method parameter with `@RequestParam` and it will do the job for you.

```
@PostMapping( "some/request/path" )
public void someControllerMethod( @RequestParam Map<String, String> body ) {
  //work with Map
}
```

Comment: this is valid on Spring Boot 2.4.2

Answer (score 23):

Add a header to your request to set content type to application/json

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -XPOST http://your.domain.com/ -d YOUR_JSON_BODY
```

this way spring knows how to parse the content.

Comment: You might need to also add an Accept header to your command: 'curl -vk -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" ' etc.

Comment: can you please explain how to add this setting to my HTML form ?

Answer (score 19):

In Spring 5

```
@PostMapping( "some/request/path" )
public void someControllerMethod( @RequestParam MultiValueMap body ) {

    // import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

    String datax = (String) body .getFirst("datax");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, with inclusion of consumer=MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE in mapping, you deserve more points sir! thank you! @RequestParam seams to be required now for picking up MultiValueMap from the request

Answer (score 14):

@RequestBody MultiValueMap paramMap

in here **Remove the @RequestBody** Annotaion

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount(@RequestBody LogingData user){
    logingService.save(user);
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/signin",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount( LogingData user){
    logingService.save(user);
    return "login";
}
```

like that

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 8):

Simply removing `@RequestBody` annotation solves the problem (tested on Spring Boot 2):

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping
    public void method(@Valid RequestDto dto) {
       // method body ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@PostMapping(path = "/my/endpoint", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Void> handleBrowserSubmissions(MyDTO dto) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

That way works for me

Comment: This is the simplest answer; works for me on Spring Boot 2.6.0 on a @RestController.

Answer (score 5):

I met the same problem when I want to process my **simple HTML form submission** (**without** using **thymeleaf** or **Spring's form tag**) in Spring MVC.

The answer of Douglas Ribeiro will work very well. But just in case, for anyone, like me, who **really want to use "@RequestBody"** in Spring MVC.

Here is the **cause** of the problem:

- Spring need to ① **recognize the "Content-Type"**, and ② **convert the
  content** to the parameter type we declared in the method's signature.
- The '**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**' is **not supported**, because, **by
  default**, the Spring cannot find a **proper HttpMessageConverter** to do
  the **converting job**, which is step ②.

Solution:

- We **manually** add a **proper HttpMessageConverter** into the **Spring's
  configuration** of **our application**.

Steps:

1. Choose the HttpMessageConverter's class we want to use. For
   '**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**', we can choose
   "org.springframework.http.converter.**FormHttpMessageConverter**".
2. Add the **FormHttpMessageConverter object** to Spring's configuration,
   by calling the "public void
   **configureMessageConverters**(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>
   converters)" method of the **"WebMvcConfigurer" implementation class**
   in our application. Inside the method, we can add any
   **HttpMessageConverter** object as needed, by using "**converters.add()**".

By the way, the **reason** why we can **access the value** by using "**@RequestParam**" is:

According to **Servlet Specification** (Section 3.1.1):

> The following are the conditions that must be met before post form
> data will be populated to the parameter set: The request is an **HTTP
> or HTTPS request**. 2. The HTTP method is **POST**. 3. The content type is
> **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. 4. The servlet has made an initial
> call of any of the **getParameter family of methods** on the **request
> object**.

So, the **value in request body** will be **populated to parameters**. But in Spring, you can **still access RequestBody**, even you can use **@RequstBody** and **@RequestParam** at the **same method's signature**.
Like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public String processForm(@RequestParam Map<String, String> inputValue,  @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, List<String>> formInfo) {
    ......
    ......
}
```

The inputValue and formInfo contains the **same data**, excpet for the type for "**@RequestParam**" is **Map**, while for "**@RequestBody**" is **MultiValueMap**.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote about an alternative in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160620/3694570).

There I wrote step by step, explaining with code. The short way:

**First**: write an object

**Second**: create a converter to mapping the model extending the AbstractHttpMessageConverter

**Third**: tell to spring use this converter implementing a WebMvcConfigurer.class overriding the configureMessageConverters method

**Fourth** and final: using this implementation setting in the mapping inside your controller the consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE and @RequestBody in front of your object.

I'm using spring boot 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn support on in spring's converter

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        // add converter suport Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        converters.stream()
                .filter(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
                .map(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class::cast)
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(converter -> converter.addSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an HTTP Header Manager if you are testing using JMeter :
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found simple way. Just add @FormProperty annotation for each field of your request domain. Of course, you should use consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE in your controller or client.
Example:

```
public class AccessTokenRequest {

    @FormProperty("client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @FormProperty("username")
    private String username;

    @FormProperty("grant_type")
    private String grantType;
}
```