# Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not working with @RequestBody for WebFlux application

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, x-www-form-urlencoded

Based on multiple thread regarding topic "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not working with @RequestBody" I haven't been successful in finding a solution for WebFlux Spring application.

I have a WebFlux Controller method:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        public Mono<AddRecipientResponse> createRecipient(@RequestBody
                                                  final MultiValueMap<String, String> formData,
                                                  @RequestHeader
                                                  final Map<String, String> headers) {
```

But when I post my reqest I'm getting this error:

```
Could not resolve parameter [0] ... RecipientController.createRecipient(long,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>): 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
```

Most of the solution rely on replacing `@RequestBody` with `@RequestParam`. However this cannot apply for my case. I need to have both `@RequestBody` and `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE`. I tried following steps described in following threads, but off of them are for Spring MVC.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70148328/18734587

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160620/18734587

Have anyone figured out how to solve 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE error for a request with `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` and `@RequestBody` for a WebFlux application?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution on my own. Request body is extracted from ServerWebExchange.getFormData(), like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public Mono<AddRecipientResponse> createRecipient(@RequestHeader final Map<String, String> headers,
                                                      ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {

        return serverWebExchange.getFormData()
                .flatMap(formData -> recipientService.createRecipient(headers, formData));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046420/resolved-org-springframework-web-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-content-ty#:%7E:text=Start%20a%20bounty-,1%20Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A)

> Spring doesn't recognize it's a RequestBody when using
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>
> Try to remove @RequestBody annotation.

I find it to be absolutely spot-on.

Answer (score -1):

I have been struggling with this a morning. From the documented annotation `@RequestParam`

> Supported for annotated handler methods in Spring MVC and Spring
> WebFlux as follows:
>
> In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query
> parameters, form data, and parts in multipart requests. This is
> because the Servlet API combines query parameters and form data into a
> single map called "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of
> the request body.
>
> In Spring WebFlux, "request parameters" map to query
> parameters only. To work with all 3, query, form data, and multipart
> data, you can use data binding to a command object annotated with
> ModelAttribute.

Then after trying with `@ModelAttribute` from the documentation of Spring WebFlux only way to come to implement this in the documentation was:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-form-data

Java with annotated controller:

> ```
> @PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
> public String createRecipient(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
>
>     MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = serverWebExchange.getFormData().block();
>     return formData.toString();
> }
> ```

Kotlin with annotated controller and coroutines:

> ```
> @PostMapping(value = ["/endpoint"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
> suspend fun createRecipient(serverWebExchange: ServerWebExchange): String? {
>     val formData: MultiValueMap<String, String> = serverWebExchange.formData.awaitSingle()
>     return formData.toString()
> }
> ```