# Spring boot handle sophisticated post request

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-post

There is an incoming post request like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/some/path' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'prop1=prop1Value' \
--data-urlencode 'prop2[prop2Inner1]=prop2Inner1Value' \
--data-urlencode 'prop2[prop2Inner2][inner3]=inner3Value' \
--data-urlencode 'prop2[prop2Inner2][inner4]=inner4Value'
```

In an php script i would get the post request data in an associative array like this automatically:

```
[
    'prop1' => 'prop1Value',
    'prop2' => [
        'prop2Inner1' => 'prop2Inner1Value',
        'prop2Inner2' => [
            'inner3' => 'inner3Value',
            'inner4' => 'inner4Value',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now im trying to handle this request in java. I **can not** change the incoming post request format. I thought that i can make a couple of Classes like this

```
@NonArgumentConstructor
@AllArgumentsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class MyRequest {
    private String prop1,
    private FirstInnerDto prop2;
}

@NonArgumentConstructor
@AllArgumentsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class FirstInnerDto {
    private String prop2Inner1;
    private SecondInnerDto prop2Inner2;
}

@NonArgumentConstructor
@AllArgumentsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class SecondInnerDto {
    private String inner3;
    private String inner4;
}
```

And than in the controller do something like this, and get an object of class 'MyRequest' filled with request data:

```
@RequestMapping("/some/path")
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponseDto> myHandler(@ModelAttribute MyRequest request) {
    // Do anything here with 'request' object

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK.value()).body(new SomeResponseDto());
}
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
"Invalid property 'prop2[prop2Inner1]' of 
bean class [com.testapp.java.myapp.Model.Dto.Request.MyRequest]: 
Property referenced in indexed property path 'prop2[prop2Inner1]' is neither an array 
nor a List nor a Map; 
returned value was [FirstInnerDto{prop2Inner1='null', prop2Inner2='null'}]"
```

Can anyone tell me what is the right way to handle such requests in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that the incoming request format cannot be changed, so you need to do some minor change at your end.

> As the incoming request is coming as an array, you need to capture it
> as an array request only like `@RequestBody MyRequest[] request` as well as other attributes which i have updated in the corresponding classes as shown below-

**Code:**

```
@RequestMapping("/some/path")
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponseDto> myHandler(@RequestBody 
                                                MyRequest[] request) {
    // Do anything here with 'request' object
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK.value()).body(new SomeResponseDto());
}
```

**Change in Pojo's**

```
@NonArgumentConstructor
@AllArgumentsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class MyRequest {
    private String prop1,
    private FirstInnerDto[] prop2;
}

@NonArgumentConstructor
@AllArgumentsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class FirstInnerDto {
    private String prop2Inner1;
    private SecondInnerDto[] prop2Inner2;
}

@NonArgumentConstructor
@AllArgumentsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class SecondInnerDto {
    private String inner3;
    private String inner4;
}
```

Comment: Doing so got this error: "No primary or single unique constructor found for class [Lcom.testapp.java.myapp.Model.Dto.Request.MyRequest;". Changed to "List"  in controller and pojos ("MyRequest[]" -> "List<MyRequest>" ) and got "No primary or single unique constructor found for interface java.util.List". Changed then to "ArrayList" and got no error, but "request" object is empty in controller

Comment: @АлександрРодригес Can you try it with the array approach without using the lombok annotations.

Comment: tried the array approach without lombok and without any constructors, setters and getters for each pojo - got error: No primary or single unique constructor found for class [Lcom.testapp.java.transferwallet.Model.Dto.Request.MyRequest;. Added constructors (empty and for all params to each pojo) - the same error.

Comment: okay, i have updated the code with ```@RequestBody``` instead of ```@ModelAttribute```, can you try it with this as it was working fine in my local with ```@RequestBody```

Comment: Nope: Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' is not supported. Isn't @RequestBody just for application/json?

Comment: No ```@RequestBody``` supports various media types such as JSON, XML, form data, plain text, and others.

Answer (score 0):

can you change your content type from default application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

[https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data#:~:text=FormHttpMessageConverter%20Basics,it%20with%20the%20method%20parameter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data#:%7E:text=FormHttpMessageConverter%20Basics,it%20with%20the%20method%20parameter).

Comment: It is already application/x-www-form-urlencoded, as you can see in curl request in the question.

Comment: Adding 'consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})' to @RequestMapping annotation didn/t work. Getting error: HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException - Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' is not supported

Answer (score 0):

So, changing pojos and controller as GD07 said (no lombok annotations; add @RequestBody) and
adding **consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE}**
to @RequestMapping annotation (as Girish Chandra Mishra) suggested, ended with such error:

```
Unsupported Media Type. Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

Debugging the error found out that the message converter handling the request is FormHttpMessageConverter, and it
can work only with MultiValueMap. So had to change controller code to this:

```
@RequestMapping(
    path="/some/path",
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE}
)
public ResponseEntity<String> myHandler(@RequestBody MultiValueMap req) {
    // Do anything here with 'req' object

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK.value()).body(req.toString());
}
```

Now it works without errors. But i still need to map this **MultiValueMap req** to my DTO's.
So it seems that the only wright way is to write my own converter,
as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160620

Any other suggestions are welcome.