# Spring boot Unsupported Media Type with @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring

I checked in several different ways, also downloaded a new project to see what to check where is bug but I still do not know the answer.

That is my RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/message")
public class MessageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createMessage(@RequestBody Message message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

That is my Model

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String sender;
    private String telephone;
    private String message;
}
```

Gradle dependencies if necessary

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.0.pr3'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

and in postman i'm getting that error

> {   "timestamp": 1495992553884,   "status": 415,   "error":
>   "Unsupported Media Type",   "exception":
>   "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
>   "message": "Content type
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
>   "path": "/message/" }

It is simplest way for rest but where I make a mistake?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for

Comment: `@RequestBody` is for getting the full body and transform that into that object. However judging from your error you are simply posting a form then you should use `@ModelAttribute` instead, this is used for binding request parameters to objects.

Comment: can you post what are you posting to the webservice

Comment: If you landed here trying to access the direct request-body input stream via `@RequestBody InputStream`, try `InputStreamResource` instead

Answer (score 74):

In Postman. under `Body`, select `raw` and choose JSON from the drop down menu that appears. Then write the JSON that is the request body. You can't use `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` with `@RequestBody`, they are used when the binding is `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you mate. you have the correct answer for people using POSTMAN...

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that when we use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this we must remove the `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public void createMessage(Message message){
        //TODO DO your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: My configuration is.
 consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE 

Still i am getting this issue

Comment: The problem with this is that the message can have null content. I think you should use @ModelAttribute Message message

Answer (score 6):

You can write the code as 
`headers.put("Content-Type",  Arrays.asList("application/json"));`
instead of 
`headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue using `$.post` Jquery. By adding correct `contentType` and `dataType` it worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/design/save",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: floorId,
        shapes: shapes,
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
   },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need a @NoArgsConstructor for the deserialization to work. If the no arguments constructor is not there, the Http message converters fail to map the json(other media type) to the Java object. And a 415 is returned

Comment: Your answer was the correct for me. I was using a data class without a no args constructor and the 415 appeared. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

1. Set debug priority level in log4j.xml to 'debug'. Found HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.
2. Put a debugger breakpoint in org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException
3. Realized that the incoming media type is text and the supported types are json and *json, although I used all - '*/*' in my annotation. Strange.
4. Anyway, in my Angular application added headers:

   readonly headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
   this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(this.model.value), {headers: this.headers})...

Answer (score 0):

What i did was to remove jackson libray and now I don't longer have that error, spent 2 days trying to figure out this, I hope this works for you!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestBody` for FORM_URL_ENCODED data. But it seems that the only supported receiving type for that is the `MultiValueMap`.

```
@PostMapping("/oauth/token", 
    consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE], 
    produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun oauth(@RequestBody body: MultiValueMap<String, String>) {
    ...
}
```

(This is Kotlin, but you get the idea.)

For any other type, Spring Web produces this `415 Unsupported Media Type` response.

On a related note, in [this article at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data), it explicitly shows that Spring should be able to fill the values into an instance of a custom class. I did not make that work.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same case with Json. Finally only this works
Here code on react

```
export function setServices(jsonString) {
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8;");

var raw = jsonString;

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8080/setservices", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));}
```

Code on controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setservices", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody  String createMessage() throws Exception {
    //do smthg

    return "Ok";    }
```

Comment: I am voting to delete as this has not much to do with  the question.