# Spring MVC: how to fix 415 response error

Tags: spring-mvc

As I didn't find any working example to fox the 415 response error, I can't still figure out why Spring can't process the following request:

```java
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/organization")
@Slf4j
public class OrganizationController {
...
    @PutMapping(value = "/public-certificates")
    public List<CertificateDTO> updateCertificates(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String companyNumber = body.getOrDefault("kbo", "unknown");
        List<CertificateDTO> certificates = organizationClient.updateCertificates(companyNumber);

        return certificates;
    }
```

and returns:

```
Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
```

Here is a CURL version of the request:

```
curl -X PUT -i http://localhost:8080/api/organization/public-certificates --data 'kbo=123.456.789'
```

Een after modifying it as follows:

```java
@PutMapping(value = "/public-certificates")
    public List<CertificateDTO> updateCertificates(@RequestBody CompanyNumber body) {
        String companyNumber = body.getKbo();
        List<CertificateDTO> certificates = organizationClient.updateCertificates(companyNumber);

        return certificates;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private class CompanyNumber {
        private String kbo;
    }
```

and using the `curl` as follows:

```
url -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT -i http://localhost:8080/api/organization/public-certificates --data '{"kbo": "0316.380.940"}'
```

didn't solve the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230121/spring-boot-unsupported-media-type-with-requestbody) helps you?

Comment: I don't really see the best answer. I've already looked here and there and still no clues. Should my `CertificateDTO` class have a default empty constructor to make it work?

Comment: try @RequestMapping refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping . You are missing media type like application/json mostly

Comment: @Mayur, useless as the controller is already annotated (see above).

Comment: Okay, then try to execute curl command with -H "Accept:application/json"

Comment: @Mayur: do you know what `-H` stands for? Useless as well :) .

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the `RequestBody` as Map.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me:

```java
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/organization")
@Slf4j
public class OrganizationController {
...
    @PutMapping(value = "/public-certificates")
    public List<CertificateDTO> updateCertificates(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String companyNumber = body.getOrDefault("kbo", "unknown");
        List<CertificateDTO> certificates = organizationClient.updateCertificates(companyNumber);

        return certificates;
    }
```

When running with teh following CURL command:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT --data '{"kbo": "0316.380.940"}' "http://localhost:8080/api/organization/public-certificates"
```