# Java Spring boot JPA circular referencing

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

using MySQL, Java, Spring Boot and JPA

I have two objects, user and module.

A user can have many modules and a module can have many users.

A module is structured the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
public class Module {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="module_users",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="module_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

A user is structured the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    public Set<Module> modules = new HashSet<>();
```

Having @JsonIgnore annotation does "work" when calling modules, but I also need to call a user and its modules ideally. Any suggestions to support both of these without crashing from circular referencing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use DTO in this case [check here](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application)

Comment: im unsure the relevance of DTO in repeat foreign referencing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use these two annotations @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference

Ref: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
public class Module {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="module_users",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="module_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

A user is structured the following way:

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    private String email;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    public Set<Module> modules = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Apreciate the suggestion, but when using this on posting a new module gives: 

  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: By adding correct contentType and dataType it will work. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230121/spring-boot-unsupported-media-type-with-requestbody . Share the postman request you are using and your controller logic