# I'm getting 415 error on spring, but same other code works

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I'm getting 415 error on spring, I used java script to send request.
I already added jackson dependency to use json, but still not working. also weird thing is that other url with same code works.

I added suggested code and it's still not working..

Client code:

```
let data = {
  id: category.id,
  act: "addAdmin",
  target: input,
};

fetch("http://localhost:8888/categoryset", {
  method: "POST",
  header: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

Server code

```
// CategorySetDTO.java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategorySetDTO {
    private String act;
    private int id = -1;
    private String target;
}

// ApiController.java
@PostMapping(value = "/categoryset", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String updateCategory(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody CategorySetDTO data) {
    return pageService.updateCategory(request, data);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `@PostMapping(..., consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, ...)` to the controller?

Comment: Sadly adding consumes did not fix 415 error..

Comment: 415 could also mean (the media type is seemingly correct!) something is "odd" with request body! ...https://stackoverflow.com/a/62289106/592355 ...your DTO is shown "as is"?(..->constructors?)

Comment: Please [edit] the post and provide a [MRE].