# REST API to consume form with values as json

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, gson

Our REST APIs consumes `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as input. The request contains form parameters with values as JSON. Eg.

```
URI :  /abc/id   
    Request Body : 
    param1 : {"name":"vineet", "age" : "9"}  --JSON
    param2 : {"city":"delhi","state":"delhi"}  --JSON
```

But when the input is mapped to the request object the values are coming as

```
        param1 : {name : vineet, age : 9},
        param2 : {city : delhi,state : delhi}
```

Qoutes are missing. so it comes as invalid JSON.

Comment: Can't help, until you show the code.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you to understand what you looking for.

[Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody MultiValueMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for)