# Ajax and Spring MVC can't get list to spring method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

When I try to send a list with ajax to a method in spring controller I get this error:

> Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

my AJAX code:

```
$('#btn-save').click(
    ajaxSend();
);

function ajaxSend() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/kepres2Web/mvc/spatiu/update",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(rects),
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (data, status, er) {},
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
}
```

my method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"}, consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public String update(@ModelAttribute("record") Spatiu spatiu,@RequestBody List<Desk> deskList) {
    System.out.println(deskList.get(0).getFill());

    dao.update(spatiu);
    //return null;
    return "redirect:view?ls&id=" + spatiu.getId();
}
```

and my button:

```
<button id="btn-save" type="submit" form="frmDetails" formaction="update">
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/actions/save.png">
    <br>Salvare
</button>
```

**EDIT**

Found out that Spring doesn't understand application/x-www-form-urlencoded as RequestBody so I removed it and added @ResponseBody on method. Now it returns and empty list.

Comment: you're setting the content type twice - once in the `contentType` option and once in the `headers` option, and you're setting it to two different values.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for for a possible solution to the message.

Comment: Removed headers. Still not working @ADyson. Same error

Comment: add consumes as application json. You only have produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to fix in your code.

1. You have defined headers 2 times. Headers defined by headers takes precedence. You need to remove that to be able to send json data your service.
2. On @RequestMapping
   you need to define consumes in order to accept the data as json. Check if you have by default json as accepted data otherwise configure explicitly using consumes.

> @RequestMapping(value = "URL", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =
>   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces =
>   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)