# @RequestMapping(headers),@RequestBody not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, axios

I have a problem configuring the header attribute in the @RequestMapping annotation.Here is my code:
HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/css/url_rearch_params.js}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    <h1>TEST FORM</h1>
     <form action="" method="post">
        <p>Type description: <input type="text" v-model="type.description"/></p>
        <p><button v-on:click="addType()"> Send </button><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>


    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data:{
                type:{description:''}
            },
            methods:{
                addType(){
                    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                                 'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                              }
                                   };
                    let newType = {description:this.type.description};
                    console.log(newType);
                    this.$http.post('/types/insert',newType,config).then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void createType(@RequestBody Type type) {
    System.out.println(type);
    typeService.createType(type);
}
```

The problem if I try to execute the method I have the following message:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

If I remove :

> headers = {“Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded”,“Content-Type =
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded”}

of the @requestpost parameter I have the following error :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type,
>   status=415). Content type
>   ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8’ not supported

N.B : I already visited this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for) but it does not solve my problem

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I highly doubt that you are actually sending an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Looks like a regular post with JSON and nothing url encoded. Also why are you messing around with headers yourself, you shouldn't need that. Remove the headers from the client (axios is smart enough to figure it out itself).

Comment: Hi, actually, if I use consumes = "application / json" the method runs fine and I have the expected result back-end side.But in the browser I have this message : There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: Because that isn’t what you are sending, you are sending json back as well...

Comment: And I do not know how to solve this problem.If you have an idea thank you for helping me.

Comment: As stated in my first comment remove the headers from your Javascript. Axios is smart enough to Figure it out.

Comment: I deleted it but the problem persists.

Comment: Also make sure you don’t have anything url-encoded left on your controller.

Comment: No I have not used url-encoded in the controller.

Comment: The only thing you need is ‘@PostMapping(/insert)’. No headers, consumes or produces on the controller and no headers on your JavaScript. You are overthinking the solution, keep it simple.

Comment: In fact, it does not solve the problem. I still have the problem of :                                         There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported                                                                                                                               in the browser

Comment: Are you preventing the default form action? You might want to replace the form tags with a div as you aren’t really using it. If that still doesn’t work you are still configuring the content type somewhere...

Comment: I tried the solution that you have proposed but it does not work.And I have not configured the content-type.

Comment: If you have that you still have headers set that send that content type. You should remove the `config` (at least the headers) from your `addType` function in javascript as well.

Comment: Yes I did that but it did not work. I created a new topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990345/type-unsupported-media-type

Comment: Thanks, as you said I delete the form tag

Answer (score -1):

Instead of headers, try `consumes`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
```

Comment: Hi, in fact, if I use consumes = "application / json" the method runs fine and I have the expected result back-end side.But in the browser I have this message : There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported.

Comment: And I do not know how to solve this problem.If you have an idea thank you for helping me.

Comment: for that you need to set Accept and Content-Type headers to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You cannot do this in browser. you can test it using some client like Postman.