# Unsupported Media Type (status 415)

Tags: html, spring-boot, axios

I have an application problem / x-www-form-urlencoded with my form.In fact, when I send the data (in json format), they are well recovered by the method that does it except that I have this error message in the browser:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type,
>   status=415). Content type
>   ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8’ not supported

Here are my different codes:

Method that retrieves the data from the form and inserts it into the database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody void createType(@RequestBody Type type) {
    typeService.createType(type);
}
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    <h1>TEST FORM</h1>
     <form action="" method="post">
        <p>Type description: <input type="text" v-model="type.description"/></p>
        <p><button v-on:click="addType()"> Send </button><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>


    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data:{
                type:{description:''}
            },
            methods:{
                addType(){
                    let newType = {description:this.type.description};
                    console.log(newType);
                    this.$http.post('/types/insert',newType).then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the different enctype (text / plain, multipart / form-data and application / json; application / x-www-form-urlencoded being the default) of the form but none allowed me to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to set the content type as (*/*) / WILDCARD & try.

Comment: `void` method with `@ResponseBody` doesn't really make sense. You aren't returning anything. Also, as mentioned in your initial question, remove the `form` tags or make sure you are preventing the default event (submitting the form) from happening.

Comment: Thanks, as you said I delete the form tag.