# Spring mvc 4 @PostMapping or @RequestMapping expose rest give 415 response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to expose rest webservice using spring mvc 4.
With these annotations in controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/services/empservice", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String testArgument(@RequestBody Employee employee){
      System.out.println("employee variable--->"+employee.getEmployeeID());
      return String.valueOf(20);
   }

  @PostMapping(value = "/services/empservices", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  public String testArguments(@RequestBody Employee emploee){
      System.out.println("employee variable--->"+employee.getEmployeeID());
      return employee.getEmployeeID();
   }
```

The response from WAS 8.5.5 gives 415 Media unsupported Status with 
response header
Accept →application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, */*

---

Accept →application/x-www-form-urlencoded

---

How to get pass this error and how to set response header for getting application/json with json response

Comment: remove header headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: in your request you need set a header property Content-Type = application/json

Comment: After removing existing headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  it is the same 415

Comment: by adding headers = "content-type=application/json" also doesnt help and it is the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should be resolved with the next issue of the [Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for/38252958#38252958) answer.

Where necessary to remove annotation `@RequestBody`