# HTTP Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring boot service

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, retrofit2

I am new to spring boot recently i am trying to do HTTP POST request from one android application through retrofit2 rest API library with application/x-www-form-url encoded but when i hit my spring boot POST service it shows me below error

> "status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media
>   Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content
>   type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not
>   supported","path":"/api/login"

[image]

**Can anyone know how to solve it?**

**Here is my code Android Code example**

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/login")
    Call<LoginData> postLogIn(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password);
}
```

ApiHandler.java

```
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.12:8080/";
    private static final long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30;
    public static Retrofit restAdapter;

    //public static final int CONNECTION_TIME_OUT = 120;
    private static Retrofit getRestAdapter() {
        if (restAdapter == null) {
            restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getClient()).build();
        }
        return restAdapter;
    }

    private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder okClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        okClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
        okClientBuilder.connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okClientBuilder.readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okClientBuilder.writeTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return okClientBuilder.build();
    }
```

PostHandler.java

```
@Override
    public void callAPI(final Context context, final ApiClientResponse callback, Object arg0) {
        this.callback = callback;
        apiService.postLogIn(Login.username, Login.password).enqueue(new Callback<LoginData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginData> call, Response<LoginData> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    LoginData loginData = response.body();
                    successLoginData = loginData;
                    successCallBack();
                } else {
                    ApiErrorHandler.handleError(context, response, errorResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginData> call, Throwable t) {
                ApiErrorHandler.handleError(context, t, errorResponse);
            }

            RetrofitErrorResponse errorResponse = new RetrofitErrorResponse() {
                @Override
                public void errorMessage(String errorMessage) {
                    failureCallBack(errorMessage);
                }

                @Override
                public void tSyncError() {

                }

                @Override
                public void invalidTokenError() {

                }
            };

        });
    }
```

LoginData.java model class

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class LoginData {
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    @Expose
    private String refreshToken;
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    private long expiresIn;
    @SerializedName("scope")
    @Expose
    private String scope;

    // getter setter 
}
```

**Here is my Spring boot application code example**

MainApplicationClass.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplicationClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplicationClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class BlogController {
    @Autowired
    BlogRespository blogRespository;
    BlogMockedData blogMockedData = BlogMockedData.getInstance();

    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public List<Blog> index() {
        return blogMockedData.fetchBlogList();
    }

    @GetMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public Blog show(@PathVariable String id) {
        int blogId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        return blogMockedData.getBlogById(blogId);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/login",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
    )
    public LoginData postLogin(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String userName = body.get("username");
        String password = body.get("password");
        return blogMockedData.getLoginToken(userName, password);
    }
```

**NOTE:** If I hit spring boot POST service from POSTMAN i get below result

[image: enter image descriptiIn here]

But if I hit the POST service from my android client side it gets me the error

> "status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media
>   Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content
>   type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not
>   supported","path":"/api/login"

Answer (score 2):

For Spring to correctly load form encoded data you need to define the endpoint parameter as:

```
public LoginData postLogin(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> body)
```

or

```
public LoginData postLogin(@RequestParam Map<String, String> body)
```

Comment: Hi @bluurr I applied your answer but still get the same error

Comment: Hi, which version of Spring boot are you using?

Comment: hi  @bluurr  
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

Comment: When you send in postman using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded do you still see the same error?

Comment: hi @bluurr when I send in postman using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
it show me **Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date →Mon, 03 Dec 2018 18:01:58 GMT
Transfer-Encoding →chunked**

Comment: Is that with the same error response body? I ran a test using the code below and that seems to load the data correctly.


@RequestMapping(value="/api/login/example", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String example(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> body) {
        return "Size:" + body.size() + ": " + body;
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184640/discussion-between-bluurr-and-abdur-razzak).

Answer (score 1):

When using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, remove the @RequestBody annotation in the parameter list of your mapped data as I can see it there.

Please read this [Spring doesn't understand application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for)

Comment: hi @dexter already apply this solution but still gets the same error

Answer (score 0):

To process a URL Encoded POST in Spring Boot ( Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded )

This does not work:

```
    public String processForm(@RequestBody RespFormDTO formDTO, 
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

This will work:

```
public String processForm(RespFormDTO formDTO,
       HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue where when header **Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded** is added to my request to Springboot app. Request body is empty.

I followed instruction is below link and it worked.

Short answer , you need to disable **HiddenHttpMethodFilter**

Link below explains reason and how to disable

https://newbedev.com/why-is-httpservletrequest-inputstream-empty

Answer (score 0):

add headers in your interface

```
public interface ApiService {
  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("/api/login")
  @Headers({
          "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
          "Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
  Call<LoginData> postLogIn(
          @Field("username") String username,
          @Field("password") String password);
}
```