# How to receive application/x-www-form-urlencoded Request parameters in Spring rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write a rest endpoint which receives application/x-www-form-urlencoded. But the endpoint does not accept request parameters for @RequestBody or @RequestParam

I Have tried using MultiValueMap to grab the request parameters. But I always get 0 parameters.
Is there a way to get request values to the MultiValueMap or some other POJO class.

`AD=&value=sometestvalue` - This is the application/x-www-form-urlencoded requestbody. I'm trying to do the request using postman

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/verification/pay/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Response testVerificationPay(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam MultiValueMap formData,
                                           HttpServletRequest servletRequest, ServiceContext serviceContext){
        log.info("!--REQUEST START--!"+formData.toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `MultiValueMap<String, String>`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/verification/pay/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response testVerificationPay(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
        System.out.println("!--REQUEST START--!" + formData.toString());
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `@RequestParam` on a POST request as the data is not in the URL as in a GET request.

You should use `@RequestBody` ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)) along with registering appropriate [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html). Most likely you should use: [FormHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html)

Comment: I have tried using @RequestBody as well still I get formData size as 0. which means no parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for tried this solution. Still the same result

Comment: I know this was quite some time ago but did you ever find a solution to this? I experience the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@ResponseBody`. Then, change to a `String`, not a `MultiValueMap`, to see if the body comes in to the request.

Comment: Tried. it gives an empty String.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the Spring documentation to handle this. would be grateful if anyone can guide me there. surely there must be a way to handle url-encoded from requests in Spring :)

Comment: then use httpservletrequest. (ex) `servletRequest.getParameter("value")`)If you still do not respond, your client is passing data in an incorrect way.