# How to handle org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I develop spring boot application used as middleware between client apps and backend application. I try to upgrade spring boot version from 1.5.6.RELEASE to 2.1.12.RELEASE.

After upgrade, there are some exceptions that I can handle later. However, I can't fix the problem related with **content type** in integration tests that I develop with spring-boot-test.

Here is the problematic service signature:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"test/lorem/ipsum/{id}"},
    produces = {"application/json"},
    consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    method = {RequestMethod.POST}
)
RedirectView testMethod(@RequestPart(value = "redirectResponse",required = true) String var1, @PathVariable("id") String var2);
```

Here is the test method:

```
@Test
public void testSuccessResponse() {
    final MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add(MockConstant.REDIRECT_RESPONSE, MockConstant.REDIRECT_SUCCESS_RESPONSE);

    final String url = "test/lorem/ipsum/" + MockConstant.ID;
    final ResponseEntity<RedirectView> responseEntity = post(
        url,
        map,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,
        RedirectView.class);

    ...
}
```

Related post method:

```
protected final <T> ResponseEntity<T> post(final String path, final Object request, final MediaType mediaType,
    final Class<T> responseType) {

    final HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, getHttpHeaders(mediaType));

    return restTemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, responseType);
}
```

Related getHttpHeaders method:

```
protected HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders(final MediaType mediaType) {

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.setContentType(mediaType);
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "tr");
    headers.set(Constant.HEADER_PLATFORM, "ios");
    headers.set(Constant.HEADER_APP_VERSION, "3.4.0");
    headers.set(Constant.HEADER_SYSTEM_VERSION, "20.0");

    return headers;
}
```

While the test is running, it cannot get into the service and thrown this exception below:

```
    org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:115)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:72)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.asMultipartHttpServletRequest(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:78)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.<init>(RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:127)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:151)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:86)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2907)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2769)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95)
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:140)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:194)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:213)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:255)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2867)
        ... 73 common frames omitted
```

I don't know what I can share any other info about the problem. If you think there should, please ask me to share with you.

Any ideas would be appreciated,
Best regards.

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` => `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

Comment: By using "RestControllerAdvice" annotation, all exceptions are handled in new ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class that I develop. Spring default ResponseEntityExceptionHandler is bypassed. How is this related with our problem? I don't understand your recommendation :/ @Zorglube

Comment: My bad, I red you question to fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think @RequestPart can only be used for multipart/form-data and multipart/mixed with the value being put into a MultipartFile

see: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html

I think for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" you should simply use MultiValueMap instead of String without any annotations. See also:

[Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody MultiValueMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for)