# FormData is missing when using Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in Spring 2.5.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Based on the answer from: [Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported for @RequestBody MultiValueMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796218/content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencodedcharset-utf-8-not-supported-for)

I'm have write post method:

```
@PostMapping (value = "test_3d_gmo", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public ResponseData<String> returnUrlCall(@RequestParam Map<String, String> param, MultiValueMap<String, String> body) {
    LOGGER.info("request param {}", param.toString());
    LOGGER.info("request body  {}", body.toSingleValueMap());
    ResponseData<String> res = new ResponseData<>();
    res.setAppData("Test");
    return res;
}
```

I'm send request to this API using postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/api/cc/test_3d_gmo?message=a' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'param1=g1' \
--data-urlencode 'param2=g2' \
--data-urlencode 'param3=g3'
```

But my body always missing, param and body only have query string message. How i can fix this ?