# Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm using OpenAPI generator to generate Spring REST APIs. Here is a fragment:

```
openapi: 3.0.2

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Auth

paths:
  '/auth/v1/token':
    post:
      operationId: getAuthToken
      requestBody:
        content:
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginRequest'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Success'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/OnlineAccount'

components:

  schemas:
    LoginRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        username:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
          format: password
        grant_type:
          type: string
      required:
        - username
        - password
        - grant_type

    OnlineAccount:
      title: OnlineAccount
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
```

It generates a Spring REST API method (only an interesting method):

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "getAuthToken", notes = "", response = OnlineAccount.class, tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = OnlineAccount.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/v1/token",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<OnlineAccount> getAuthToken(@ApiParam(value = "", required=true) @RequestPart(value="username", required=true)  String username,@ApiParam(value = "", required=true) @RequestPart(value="password", required=true)  String password,@ApiParam(value = "", required=true) @RequestPart(value="grant_type", required=true)  String grantType);
```

Then I want to call it from my integration test using `RestTemplate`:

```
    RequestEntity<String> requestEntity =
        RequestEntity.post(
                new URL("http://localhost:" + applicationPort + "/auth/v1/token").toURI())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .body("username%3Dtest%40test-email.com%26password%3Dpassword");

    ResponseEntity<OnlineAccount> loginResponse =
        restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, OnlineAccount.class);
```

And I get an error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:213) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:131) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:255) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2771) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:72) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.asMultipartHttpServletRequest(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.<init>(RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:134) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

I've debugged a little the server side and it looks like it expects a multipart content, but I don't understand why.

This is one of several attempts to call the service. I've checked some solutions using `MultiValueMap`, also these questions, but no success:

[Http Post request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin/38252762#38252762)

[Spring MVC - @RequestParam causing MissingServletRequestParameterException with x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731070/spring-mvc-requestparam-causing-missingservletrequestparameterexception-with/33732140#33732140)

My Spring boo version: 2.3.3-RELEASE (fails also with 2.3.1-RELEASE)

Comment: It works exactly as expected. You are sending a body and not parameters. To send parameters you will need the multivalue map. And why `@RequestPart`? That would only work with a multipart form, you should be using `@RequestParam` instead. In short the generated method doesn't really make sense.

Comment: So in my opinion it looks like OpenAPI Spring generator is broken that produces a `@RequestPart`

Comment: I doubt it is broken as it just uses the contract you have. Did you create the contract yourself or did you get one supplied?

Comment: By myself, but the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the only thing making problems. When I change it to `application/json` and refactor the code, then it works just fine. If it is not broken, then any idea what can be the reason that it generates `@RequestPart`? I don't use `multipart/form-data` - what I could understand then.

Comment: So your contract isn't correct. The contract indicates, judging from the types being used, you need to either use json, or stop using types and just use a form.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@RequestPart` which expects `MultipartFile` content type. Change `@RequestPart` if not specially required.

Read [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html)

Comment: I'm using an openapi generator which has/had a bug. I don't have much influence on the generated Java interface API

Answer (score 2):

there is a bug in open api generator (opened 5 days ago)
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/7794

Note that there is a commit referenced on this issue which seems to fix the bug.
It's a one-liner mustache template formParams.mustache.

If you rely on openapi-generator-maven-plugin, you could try using the templateDirectory config and put there the mustache template proposed as a fix.
Might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this.  The behaviour was introduced in 4.3.0 in 2020, and fixed in 2022.  More details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71954528/18619318

I found that upgrading to 6.0.0-beta gave the behavior I was looking for.  Note that naming of helper classes has changed, if you use the "spring" generator.